# Masstransit State Machine - Retry Mechanism

Tags: masstransit, saga, automatonymous

In case a message is being "retried" as a result of an exception, is it being returned physically to the queue? to the beginning? to the end? Is it re-processed after the existed messages in queue? Is it being kept in application memory?

I have not found any description for the masstransit retry mechanism **flow** in the documentation.

Please refer me to any documentation that explains it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MassTransit will retry the message within the same consumer delivery - the retry is only on the consumer/saga/handler delivery pipeline. In the case of a saga, the database transaction (if present) is aborted, and a new transaction is started - including re-reading the saga instance from the database.

The message is not returned to the queue for other workers to process.

If the retry policy limit is reached, the message is moved to the *_error* queue.

Comment: If i do not count on the messages to come in a certain order, and the current saga delivery pipeline cannot progress because the state has not reached the desired one, or even it has not been created yet, you say that the current worker is "stuck" on this message? using interval for retry - enables the current worker to handle other messages at the meantime?

Comment: If you aren't in a state to process the message you should use a scheduled redelivery of it. Either via scheduling a message yourself or just telling MassTransit to redeliver it using scheduled redelivery.